# Como alterar o idioma da IDE Netbeans No Mac?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Boa noite,

Podem me ajudar a altera o idioma no IDE netbeans 8.2 ? o meu sistema Operacional esta em Português mas como a primeira versão do netbeans instalado estava em inglês acho que deve ter influenciado a versão portuguesa instalado actualmente, tem como alterar manualmente? pelos menus não encontro

Comment: A resposta de alguma forma te atendeu? Precisa de mais alguma informação para aceitá-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navegue até o diretório de instalação do Netbeans:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8\etc
```

Abre o arquivo `netbeans.conf` e procure pela linha com a chave `netbeans_default_options`:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"
```

Adicione o seguinte no final da linha:

```
"-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"
```

Reinicie o Netbeans!

Comment: ai meu caro, Murillo Goulart diz quiser no Mac desculpa.

Comment: @Anselmo só o caminho que deve mudar, a princípio, mas a configuração é a mesma!

Comment: Acabei de pensar nisso, estou a procura do arquivo

Comment: Não achei o arquivo, estou a reinstalar o OS.

Answer (score 1):

Alterar o idioma para inglês no mac:

1. abra o terminal e acesse o diretório **/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc**
2. digite **sudo vim netbeans.conf** (isso abre o arquivo netbeans.conf em modo admin)
3. encontre a linha iniciada com **netbeans_default_options**
4. ao final desta linha, antes do " adicione **-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US**
5. salve o arquivo e reexecute o netbeans.

No meu caso, esta linha ficou assim:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"
```

**OBS:** meu netbeans é a versão 8.2. Caso você tenha outra instalada, basta ajustar o caminho até a pasta `/etc`.